# Proving that a set is not compact

Tags: proof-explanation, compactness

Consider the unit sphere without the origin, i.e., the set of $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$, but $(x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$.

I am trying to show that this set is not compact by finding an open cover without a finite subcover. The underlying reason is surely that it's not closed. I can find a sequence of elements converging to the zero vector, which is not in the set. But I can't think of a suitable open cover.

Comment: Careful, most would call that a ball, not a sphere (which is hollow).

Comment: The analog of this in dimension 1 would be $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$.  I can cover this with open sets of the form $(-1+1/n,0) \cup (0,1-1/n)$ and let $n\geq 2$ go to $\infty$.  This clearly can't be reduced finitely because the sets in the cover are nested.  Try the same thing in your case.

Comment: A careful reading of the proof that [sequential compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space) is equivalent to compactness in a metric space could have led you to understanding how to construct the open cover suggested by @Randall.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathcal{U}=\{U_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where the sets $U_n$ are defined

$$U_n = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\ | \ \frac{1}{n} < x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \}$$

Answer (score 2):

For all $2\le n\in\mathbb N$, the closed ball of radius $\frac1n$, $B_n=\{p\mid\|p\|\le\frac1n\}$ is closed set, indeed. So, their complement $A_n=B_n^c$ is open set.

And, $\cup_2^\infty A_n=(\cap_2^\infty B_n)^c$, and $\cap_2^\infty B_n=\{(0,0,0)\}$, so $\mathfrak X=\{A_n\}_{n\ge2}$ is open covering of your set $S$.

But it doesn't have finite subcovering. Why?

> If $n<m$, then $A_n\subset A_m$. So, if $F\subset\{n\in\mathbb N\mid2\le n\}$ is finite set, then $\cup_{n\in F}A_n=A_{\max F}$. It does not cover your set $S$. So $\mathfrak X$ has no finite subcovering.